# nvl is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, function, built-in, isnull, nvl

I am executing below query on SQL Server but getting error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.p_id "Id",
(TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY') + least(SIGN(("sysdate" - to_date('01-Aug-' | | TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0)) "Year"

FROM 
   t1,
   t7,
   t9
WHERE 
   t9.ei_id(+)          = t7.e_id
AND (t7.e_student        = t1.p_id)
AND (t7.e_module         = t8.m_id)
AND (NVL(t9.ei_q18m06, t7.e_end) > '31-Jul-' | | (TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY') + least(SIGN(("sysdate" - to_date('01-Aug-' | | TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0) + - 5))

Error:

'nvl' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Any idea how this can be avoided?

Comment: SQL server or Oracle?

Comment: How to avoid?  
Hire someone that can translate PLSQL to TSql. You have more problems than just the NVL problem.

Answer (score 7):

`NVL` is Oracle syntax

The corresponding function in SQL server is `ISNULL` :

```
AND (ISNULL(t9.ei_q18m06, t7.e_end) > '31-Jul-' | | (TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY') + least(SIGN(("sysdate" - to_date('01-Aug-' | | TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0) + - 5))
```

Even better, use COALESCE() which is standard ANSI and accepted by both Oracle and SQL server

```
AND (COALESCE(t9.ei_q18m06, t7.e_end) > '31-Jul-' | | (TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY') + least(SIGN(("sysdate" - to_date('01-Aug-' | | TO_CHAR("sysdate", 'YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-RRRR'))), 0) + - 5))
```

[SQL NULL Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Comment: or use `COALESCE()` which is standard ANSI, and should be usable on all platforms.